# Can the range for double in Java be extended?

Tags: java, primitive

The data type double covers a range from 4.94065645841246544e-324d to 1.79769313486231570e+308d. If I have to deal with numbers less than 4.94065645841246544e-324d, is there a data type I can use?

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a data type I can use?

**Yes**<sup>**1**</sup>. You might use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). The linked Javadoc says (in part) that it provides *immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers*.

<sup>**1**</sup>`BigDecimal` is not a *primtive* type (and the range of *primtive types* is mandated by the specification).